# vis.js Network: add label to edge

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I want to make a web application, in which I can make finite state automaton by selecting actions from menu. I have found [this example from visjs](http://visjs.org/examples/network/other/manipulation.html) but I need to add some functionality and I can not figure how to edit this example.
So for example, when user wants to add edge, I want him to set the label on the edge so I add

```
 var edgeLabel = prompt("Please enter edge label", "");
```

in code. But how can I now set the label of new edge to edgeLabel? Is this possible?
This the first time I am working with javascript so I apologize for stupid questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add **manipulation** in the options to edit the edge label.

Example:

```
   var options = {
   manipulation: {
    editEdge: function(nodeData,callback) {
      nodeData.label = prompt("Please enter edge label", ""); 
       callback(nodeData);   }   
    }
}
```

Always check documentation: http://visjs.org/docs/network/manipulation.html

Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e7n0grct/17/